# Gradle build fails on packageRunBuild Segmentation Fault

Tags: gradle, segmentation-fault, ubuntu-19.04, liferay-7.2

I cannot get Gradle (v4.10.2) to build my Liferay portlet project on my Ubuntu 19.04 machine. Please see errors in log below.

It looks like Gradle has no issue running the npmInstall command, which to me sounds like Node and npm are installed and working.

node and npm version:

`build/node/bin/node -v; build/node/bin/npm -v`

Results in:

```
v10.15.1
6.4.1
```

It isn't until the build reaches the 'packageRunBuild' process that it fails. This is the output of the build command run with the -debug flag when trying to build one of the npm React portlets:

```
23:19:42.502 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb cli   'build' ]
23:19:42.502 [QUIET] [system.out] npm info using npm@6.4.1
23:19:42.502 [QUIET] [system.out] npm info using node@v10.15.1
23:19:42.541 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
23:19:42.542 [QUIET] [system.out] npm info lifecycle advising-web@1.0.0~prebuild: advising-web@1.0.0
23:19:42.542 [QUIET] [system.out] npm info lifecycle advising-web@1.0.0~build: advising-web@1.0.0
23:19:42.545 [QUIET] [system.out] 
23:19:42.545 [QUIET] [system.out] > advising-web@1.0.0 build /home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/brown/modules/advising-web
23:19:42.545 [QUIET] [system.out] > babel --source-maps -d build/resources/main/META-INF/resources src/main/resources/META-INF/resources && liferay-npm-bundler
23:19:42.545 [QUIET] [system.out] 
23:19:42.638 [QUIET] [system.out] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
23:19:42.639 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb lifecycle advising-web@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
23:19:42.639 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb lifecycle advising-web@1.0.0~build: PATH: :/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/brown/modules/advising-web/node_modules/.bin:/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/build/node/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/home/andrew/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin:/opt/gradle/gradle-4.10.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/db/bin:/home/andrew/jpm/bin:/home/andrew/jpm/bin
23:19:42.639 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb lifecycle advising-web@1.0.0~build: CWD: /home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/brown/modules/advising-web
23:19:42.639 [QUIET] [system.out] npm info lifecycle advising-web@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
23:19:42.640 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb stack Error: advising-web@1.0.0 build: `babel --source-maps -d build/resources/main/META-INF/resources src/main/resources/META-INF/resources && liferay-npm-bundler`
23:19:42.640 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb stack Exit status 139
23:19:42.640 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/build/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
23:19:42.640 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
23:19:42.641 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/build/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
23:19:42.641 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
23:19:42.641 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
23:19:42.641 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
23:19:42.641 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb pkgid advising-web@1.0.0
23:19:42.641 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb cwd /home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/brown/modules/advising-web
23:19:42.641 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb Linux 5.0.0-31-generic
23:19:42.641 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb argv "/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/build/node/bin/node" "/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/build/node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--production" "false" "--loglevel" "verbose" "--progress" "true" "run-script" "build"
23:19:42.641 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb node v10.15.1
23:19:42.641 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb npm  v6.4.1
23:19:42.641 [QUIET] [system.out] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
23:19:42.641 [QUIET] [system.out] npm ERR! errno 139
23:19:42.642 [QUIET] [system.out] npm ERR! advising-web@1.0.0 build: `babel --source-maps -d build/resources/main/META-INF/resources src/main/resources/META-INF/resources && liferay-npm-bundler`
23:19:42.642 [QUIET] [system.out] npm ERR! Exit status 139
23:19:42.642 [QUIET] [system.out] npm ERR! 
23:19:42.642 [QUIET] [system.out] npm ERR! Failed at the advising-web@1.0.0 build script.
23:19:42.642 [QUIET] [system.out] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
23:19:42.643 [QUIET] [system.out] npm verb exit [ 139, true ]
23:19:42.644 [QUIET] [system.out] npm timing npm Completed in 167ms
23:19:42.647 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED
23:19:42.647 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command '/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/build/node/bin/node'' finished with exit value 139 (state: FAILED)
23:19:42.647 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute executeNode for :brown:modules:advising-web:packageRunBuild'
23:19:42.647 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute executeNode for :brown:modules:advising-web:packageRunBuild' completed
23:19:42.647 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository] Fingerprinting property digestFile (Output) for task ':brown:modules:advising-web:packageRunBuild'
23:19:42.647 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
23:19:42.647 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':brown:modules:advising-web:packageRunBuild'
23:19:42.647 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Task :brown:modules:advising-web:packageRunBuild'
23:19:42.647 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Task :brown:modules:advising-web:packageRunBuild' completed
23:19:42.647 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] :brown:modules:advising-web:packageRunBuild (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.301 secs.
23:19:42.647 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Task worker for ':': released lock on :
23:19:42.648 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1.15 completed (1 worker(s) in use)
23:19:42.648 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Task worker for ':': released lock on root.1.15
23:19:42.648 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]] finished, busy: 0.5 secs, idle: 0.008 secs
23:19:42.648 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.0 secs, idle: 0.504 secs
23:19:42.648 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 4,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.0 secs, idle: 0.504 secs
23:19:42.648 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 5,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.0 secs, idle: 0.5 secs
23:19:42.648 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 6,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.0 secs, idle: 0.5 secs
23:19:42.648 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.0 secs, idle: 0.506 secs
23:19:42.648 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker Thread 8,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.0 secs, idle: 0.499 secs
23:19:42.648 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 7,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.0 secs, idle: 0.499 secs
23:19:42.648 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph] Timing: Executing the DAG took 0.511 secs
23:19:42.648 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Run tasks'
23:19:42.648 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Run tasks' completed
23:19:42.649 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date
23:19:42.649 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1 completed (0 worker(s) in use)
23:19:42.649 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker Thread 8: released lock on root.1
23:19:42.649 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Run build'
23:19:42.649 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Run build' completed
23:19:42.650 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for file content cache (/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/.gradle/4.10.2/fileContent)
23:19:42.650 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on file content cache (/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/.gradle/4.10.2/fileContent).
23:19:42.650 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for task history cache (/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/.gradle/4.10.2/taskHistory)
23:19:42.650 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on task history cache (/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/.gradle/4.10.2/taskHistory).
23:19:42.651 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for Build Output Cleanup Cache (/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup)
23:19:42.651 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on Build Output Cleanup Cache (/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup).
23:19:42.651 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for cache directory md-supplier (/home/andrew/.gradle/caches/4.10.2/md-supplier)
23:19:42.651 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cache directory md-supplier (/home/andrew/.gradle/caches/4.10.2/md-supplier).
23:19:42.652 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for cache directory md-rule (/home/andrew/.gradle/caches/4.10.2/md-rule)
23:19:42.652 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cache directory md-rule (/home/andrew/.gradle/caches/4.10.2/md-rule).
23:19:42.652 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
23:19:42.652 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
23:19:42.652 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 4 resolution results binary files in 0.0 secs
23:19:42.652 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopping 0 deployment handles
23:19:42.652 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopped deployment handles
23:19:42.652 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for file hash cache (/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/.gradle/4.10.2/fileHashes)
23:19:42.652 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on file hash cache (/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/.gradle/4.10.2/fileHashes).
23:19:42.652 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore] VCS Checkout Cache (/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/.gradle/vcs-1) has last been fully cleaned up 0 hours ago
23:19:42.652 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache VCS Checkout Cache (/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/.gradle/vcs-1) was closed 0 times.
23:19:42.652 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache VCS metadata (/home/andrew/LiferayDevStudio/liferay-workspace/.gradle/4.10.2/vcsMetadata-1) was closed 0 times.
23:19:42.653 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has finished executing the build.
23:19:42.681 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientInputForwarder] Dispatching close input message: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput@6bdf8fa2
23:19:42.681 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 14: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput
23:19:42.682 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':brown:modules:advising-web:packageRunBuild'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=6614, address=[d19d7f26-2ec8-4f88-850d-073554e0bce5 port:35085, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1571627968001, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=cfe5efe0-7883-49eb-8964-864a4b090c23,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64,daemonRegistryDir=/home/andrew/.gradle/daemon,pid=6614,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
23:19:42.682 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Finished
23:19:42.682 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: connection stop
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, Gradle or npm was referring to my local npm and node instead of the project's.  I proved it by completely uninstalling node and npm.  Builds are now succeeding without issue.

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same error but I don't want to remove my local node/npm installation. Is there a way to bypass this and prevent it from using the local one?

Comment: I honestly couldn't figure that out without uninstalling Node locally.  It may be a good idea to reach out to the Liferay community about the issue. Maybe it's a bug?

Comment: same issue here, they really need more linux users among their developers... I had to uninstall my local installation, if you guys fixed going via another way, please post here. I would rather keep my local software.

Comment: Shortly after running into this issue I was forced to switch to a Mac to prevent more hiccups in the future.  I would definitely recommend logging a ticket with Liferay if you haven't already.